# Calculate elapsed time (DATEDIFF) while subtracting time for break and lunch periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I have a table that looks like:

```
job | start_time               | end_time
----------------------------------------------------------
1   | 2020-08-31 09:46:00.000  |  2020-08-31 12:37:00.000
2   | 2020-08-31 09:54:00.000  |  2020-08-31 10:24:00.000
3   | 2020-08-31 05:52:00.000  |  2020-08-31 06:32:00.000
4   | 2020-08-31 05:02:00.000  |  2020-08-31 13:24:00.000
```

I need to calculate the `elapsed_time` in minutes between the `start_time` and `end_time` but subtracts 15 minutes if the `elapsed_time` spans  `8:45am` and `9:00am` and/or 30 minutes if `elapsed_time` spans `11:30am` and `12:00pm`.

Output should look like this:

```
job | start_time               | end_time                 | elapsed_time
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 2020-08-31 09:46:00.000  |  2020-08-31 12:37:00.000 | 141
2   | 2020-08-31 09:54:00.000  |  2020-08-31 10:24:00.000 | 30
3   | 2020-08-31 05:52:00.000  |  2020-08-31 06:32:00.000 | 40
4   | 2020-08-31 05:02:00.000  |  2020-08-31 13:24:00.000 | 457
```

Thank you for any assistance!

**EDIT:**

I currently calculate minutes with:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, start_time, end_time) FROM jobtran
```

then export the dataset to excel and manually calculate from there.

Comment: What if the period *overlaps* with the two fixed ranges, say from 8:50 AM to 11:40 AM?

Comment: If that case occurs then I would like it to subtract 15 minutes (5 minutes from 8:45-8:50 and the 10 minutes from 11:30-11:40)

Comment: I wish I could say I have an excel formula to calculate - I am manually calculating.

Comment: Well if you consider the logic you are using to calculate it manually, then try and convert that to computational logic... thats how I approach any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following returns the desired results for the presented sample data. However it assumes a time period is always within a single day. And it assumes that no time period starts or finished within the break time (I'll leave that for you as an exercise).

The trick is to use a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression to detect when an overlap occurs and adjust for it.

Note also the use of the sub-query/derived table to avoid having to repeat the same converts and static values throughout the query.

```
declare @Test table (job int, start_time datetime, end_time datetime);

insert into @Test (job, start_time, end_time)
values
(1, '2020-08-31 09:46:00.000',  '2020-08-31 12:37:00.000'),
(2, '2020-08-31 09:54:00.000',  '2020-08-31 10:24:00.000'),
(3, '2020-08-31 05:52:00.000',  '2020-08-31 06:32:00.000'),
(4, '2020-08-31 05:02:00.000',  '2020-08-31 13:24:00.000');

select job, start_time, end_time
  , datediff(minute, start_time, end_time) [Total Mins]
  , datediff(minute, start_time, end_time)
  - case when start_time < end_break and end_time > start_break then 15 else 0 end
  - case when start_time < end_lunch and end_time > start_lunch then 30 else 0 end [Adjusted Mins]
from (
  select job
    , convert(time, start_time) start_time
    , convert(time, end_time) end_time
    , convert(time, '08:45am') start_break
    , convert(time, '09:00am') end_break
    , convert(time, '11:30am') start_lunch
    , convert(time, '12:00pm') end_lunch
  from @Test
) X;
```

Results

```
job | start_time                | end_time                  | Total Mins    | Adjusted Mins
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 2020-08-31 09:46:00.000   | 2020-08-31 12:37:00.000   | 171           | 141
2   | 2020-08-31 09:54:00.000   | 2020-08-31 10:24:00.000   | 30            | 30
3   | 2020-08-31 05:52:00.000   | 2020-08-31 06:32:00.000   | 40            | 40
4   | 2020-08-31 05:02:00.000   | 2020-08-31 13:24:00.000   | 502           | 457
```

Things to consider if/when taking into account a time period which starts or ends in the break/lunch:

1. If a time period begins *and* ends within a period then the total minutes should be zero - this is a special case, and once handled you can ignore in the rest of the logic.
2. If the start partway through a break period then the amount of time to subtract is the difference between the period start time and the break end time.
3. If you end partway through a break period then the amount of time to subtract is the different between the break start time and the period end time.

Note: If you setup your sample data like this in future you will get assistance much faster.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now looking at it the case method to determine when/if to subtract minutes makes so much sense. I am frustrated I didn't think of that before posted this question.